# MVC DataAnnotation Accept No Spaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I'm developing a Login View in MVC5.

I would like to set at the ViewModel level a DataAnnotation to state the the field does NOT accept empty spaces.

Is there a Data Annotation in MVC (something like [NoSpaces] that can be used to NOT allow a string field to contain "spaces" ?

Comment: You want the RegularExpression validator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx I am nut good with regular expressions, but this validator is the one you need.

Comment: OK ...may I ask if you requested to close this question?

Comment: Wasn't me that requested the question be closed.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

How about this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\S*$", ErrorMessage = "No white space allowed")]
```

Comment: ...that will allow any character but spaces, is that right?

Comment: From msdn - Matches any non-white-space character.

Comment: If you find yourself using a DataAnnotation like this in multiple places, it can be handy to make a custom class that inherits from RegularExpressionAttribute and just has an empty constructor that passes the parameters you are using into the base constructor.

Comment: This is very expensive and does not follow DRY. There is a more performant way. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest but robust thing I can think of is to look at how existing code works, or how existing data annotation work.

For example, let's look at the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute` class.

Here's the definition only (just to keep short):

```cs
namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class StringLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public StringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength);

        public int MinimumLength { get; set; }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name);
       
        public override bool IsValid(object value);
    }
}
```

So I would simply copy the original implementation source code from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/StringLengthAttribute.cs) and customize it to my needs. For example, to obtain a signature like this (if I understood correctly and this is what you wanted):

```cs
public StringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength, int minLength = 0, allowEmptySpaces = true);
```

For more in-depth info, I would also read the Microsoft docs on the [ValidationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute?view=net-5.0) class, which is your base class for custom validation data annotations.

**EDIT:**

I would **NOT** rely on Regular Expressions to validate data in cases where I just need to exclude empty strings or strings containing only white space(s), because **Regular Expressions are very expensive** to process (and require a lot of memory allocation, because of an expression compiler, a state machine, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

**If this is convenient for anyone, I got pass this issue by doing this on the client:**

//trim each form input

```
var $form = $("#myForm");
$form.find("input:text").each(function(){
   var $self= $(this);
   $self.va($self.val().trim());
});
```

//then validate before submit

```
if($form.valid()){ $form.submit(); }
```

// on the server `ModelState.Isvalid` does verify each item with `[Required]` and won't accept only white spaces from an input (but this means additional roundtrip to server and it's not always convenient)

Comment: This is not a good practice to do it at the client side. It will work fine as long as you control the client, but if someone would send e request in a different way, your server won't even handle this scenario. Server should implement that check ALWAYS..